# DES Encryption in asp.net to php

Tags: php, asp.net, des

I'm trying to achive the same DES encription that I've in an asp.net code but in PHP.

The asp code looks like the following:

```
 public static string Encrypt(string originalString)
   {
       if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(originalString))
       {
           throw new ArgumentNullException("The string which needs to be encrypted can not be null.");
       }

       System.Security.Cryptography.DESCryptoServiceProvider cryptoProvider = new System.Security.Cryptography.DESCryptoServiceProvider();
       MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
       System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream cryptoStream = new System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream(memoryStream, cryptoProvider.CreateEncryptor(bytes, bytes), System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode.Write);

       StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream);
       writer.Write(originalString);
       writer.Flush();
       cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
       writer.Flush();

       return Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)memoryStream.Length);
   }
```

Is there any equivalent available in php

```
function get_encrypted_key($key)
{
    $salt = 'abcdefgh';
    $block = mcrypt_get_block_size('des', 'cbc');
    $pad = $block - (strlen($key) % $block);
    $key .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
    return bin2hex(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_DES, $salt, $key, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $salt));
}
```

Comment: did you try anything? add some php code

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried googling?

http://us.php.net/crypt

```
$hashed = crypt('text_to_crypt');
```